# How can i change QMainWindow to QDialog

Tags: qt

I am new in Qt. I have made a project in Qt. 
Now I need to change the `QMainWindow` into `QDialog`. 
How can I do this without deleting all my project?
If a change the base mainwindow into `QDialog`, it is necessary to make a new window for being main?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on if you have a `.ui` file or not.

If so, you could edit the .ui and change the line

```
<widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
```

To

```
<widget class="QDialog" name="MainWindow">
```

Also, think about if classes like `QMenuBar`, `QToolBar` and `QStatusBar` are necessary in your project. Qt Designer puts them in the `.ui` file by default and because they are used by `QMainWindow`.

After that, you should change the base class for your `MainWindow`. You should have something like this:

```
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
```

So you need change `QMainWindow` by `QDialog`.

```
#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QDialog
{
```

If you don't have a `.ui` file, the first step is no necessary (obviously :))

Of course, you will need to check if you are using any `QMainWindow` method which is not implemented by `QDialog` in order to avoid compilation error and lack of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can freely use any type of `QWidget` as main. The main window is whatever you decide it to be, typically the one you create and show in your `main()` function. So you can freely change your base class to `QDialog` and it will probably just work.

However, if you used Qt Designer (either directly or through Qt Creator) to create the `.ui` file containing all the widgets rather than coding the interface by hand, and you don't want to go through that hassle again, it can be a bit tricky.

One way is to create a new `QDialog` and then simply copy-paste the designed window contents to the new window. This is the easiest approach, but you may lose some properties that you set in the designer because not everything is copied.

A more tricky, but also more powerful way is to edit the created `.ui` file by hand. It's just a simple XML file, after all. Look for the `class` attribute and change `class="QMainWindow"` to `class="QDialog"`. You should also look for properties and check whether these properties are defined in `QDialog` by looking at the docs. If they are QMainWindow-specific, then just delete them carefully.

Of course, you should back up your project (or commit it to the source control system) prior to playing around with XML because you may screw up something so that the designed will simply obliterate parts of your files it can't parse.